# NSOpenPanel hangs java app

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, java-native-interface

I have a `Swing` app and make a `JNI` method call that opens a `NSOpenPanel`. On some computers (I didn't find similarities between them, unfortunately) it completely hangs the app. On most computers it works correctly. If the code hangs the app on a particular Mac, it does it every time it executes.

Here is how I open a NSOpenPanel:

```
JNF_COCOA_ENTER(env);    
// My helper Obj-c object to make a selector call
OpenFileObject *openFile = [[OpenFileObject alloc] init];    
if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    [openFile showOpenFileDialog];
else
    [JNFRunLoop performOnMainThread:@selector(showOpenFileDialog) on:openFile withObject:nullptr waitUntilDone:TRUE];
// ...Handles results    
JNF_COCOA_EXIT(env);
```

and here is `showOpenFileDialog` method:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:canChooseFiles];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:canChooseFolders];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:allowMultiSelection];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
[panel setTitle:dialogTitle];

if ([panel runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    urls = [[panel URLs] copy];
else
    urls = nullptr;
```

and here is a hang report: https://gist.github.com/4207956

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. The problem was due to another app using the Accessibility API of MacOS. When a modal dialog is shown, the main Java frame doesn't respond to required native Accessibility API calls and this hangs the whole app. Avoiding native modal dialogs solves the problem.

For example, for `NSOpenPanel` we should change `[panel runModal]` to `[panel beginSheetModalForWindow]`. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, I doubt this has anything to do with your problem, but I would be wary of using `nullptr` and `TRUE` as arguments to `performOnMainThread:...` Instead I would do:

`[JNFRunLoop performOnMainThread:@selector(showOpenFileDialog) on:openFile withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`

Just to be on the safe side.

From the stack trace, assuming that is all one big stack and you just separated it to add commentary about your helper object method call, it seems like the code path being taken is the one where `[NSThread isMainThread]` returns NO. This must mean it's on a background thread (`__NSThreadPerformPerform` is then doing the bidding of `JNFRunLoop`).

The stack never gets out of the initialization path for the `NSOpenPanel`, and somehow, way deep down at the bottom, it is again accessing run loop things. In my mind, it seems like there is some kind of deadlock happening.

If `JNFRunLoop` is waiting in another thread on the execution of the `showOpenFileDialog` method to complete on the main run loop, and something in `openPanel` is trying to wait on things in that same run loop, that might cause a deadlock.

I am unfamiliar with the integration between Java and Cocoa, but might there be some way to avoid executing the first snippet of code on a non-main thread?

Alternatively, can you try using:

`[openFile performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showOpenFileDialog) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`

in the non main thread path?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I did find this talk of a crash in a similar stack, due to buffer overrun: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/130423-nssavepanel-crashing-on-instantiation.html

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better solution to this problem.

The deadlock is caused by two threads waiting on each other: the AppKit main thread and AWT event thread. Your Java code that calls the native method is running on the AWT event thread. The native method blocks the AWT event thread while waiting for the code that creates the NSOpenPanel to be performed on the AppKit main thread. Meanwhile, other events may be processed on the AppKit main thread, and if those events involve AWT windows, upcalls may be made to Java. As Java prefers to operate on its UI using the AWT, the upcalls may post an event on the AWT event queue and block waiting for the event to be processed. But the event will never be processed as long as the AWT event thread is blocked in your native method. Hence, a deadlock.

The solution is to run your Java code that calls the native method from a new Java thread, so that this background thread is blocked instead of the AWT event thread. If you have code that must run on the AWT event thread that needs the result of this computation, have it create a java.awt.SecondaryLoop and run that loop while waiting for the thread that calls your native method to receive the result. The SecondaryLoop will process the events posted by the upcalls, thus allowing the AppKit main thread to continue working, and eventually creating your NSOpenPanel. The javadoc for SecondaryLoop has an example of how to do this.